# Context passed to template in Django

Tags: django, templates

There is something I don't get in Django template system. I have a FileField in my model called myfile. If I pass an instance of my model to a template, I can access file.size (this is an example). Where does the `file.size` variable come from? It's not part of the FileField class as far as I know. A small test:

```
def save(self):
    super(UploadItem, self).save()
    import logging; logging.debug(file.size)
```

This snippet generates this error: `type object 'file' has no attribute 'size'`

Is Django doing this via magic of some kind?

Comment: Please include enough of your model definition that we can see the class line, the line that defines the File Field and the save method all in one tidy spot.  The code you've shown here can't possible work because there's no `self.file.size`.  But it's impossible to know the field name of your FileField without more complete code.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to retrieve the upload file's on-disk filename, or a URL that refers to that file, or the file's size, you can use the `name`, `url` and `size` attributes; see Managing files.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/files/

Comment: is there a way to access filename from Model side?(i need this to create a slug)